# Authentication and ID's in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, authentication, web-applications, dependencies

My friend built a big form application in CakePHP. It has a central model called "Player" and a bunch of tables and models representing different categories of questions in the form. She asked me to help implementing Auth and we've been having some trouble. I was able to link User and Player together as per the Simple Authentication tutorial on the Cake website but I'm having trouble implementing Auth on the tables related to Player. The problem occurs on the "add"-like  sections of the app. Before my implementation the add function looked like this:

```
public function name( $id =null) //Create the TEAM team name ,type
{

        $this->Team->create();  
        //$this->request->data['Team']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id'); 
        if ($this->Team->save($this->request->data)) 
        {
            $idt=$this->Team->id;       
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Team' .$idt . ' has been saved'));

            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'position', $idt));
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Team could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }   
        $players = $this->Team->Player->find('list' , array('conditions' => array('Player.id' => $id)));
        $this->set(compact('players'));

}
```

Once this has been submitted a Team is created and the player_id is set. However when I uncomment the commented line where I read the user id, the player id does not write to the database which messes up every subsequent insertion. All tables have a column for both user_id and player_id although user does not have a column for player_id. Don't really know how relevant these are but here are the associations in the models:

User

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Player' => array(
        'className' => 'Player',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ));
```

Player

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $hasMany = array(
    'ContIllnessDetail' => array(
        'className' => 'ContIllnessDetail',
        'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'ContInjuryDetail' => array(
        'className' => 'ContInjuryDetail',
        'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'NewIllnessDetail' => array(
        'className' => 'NewIllnessDetail',
        'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'NewInjuryDetail' => array(
        'className' => 'NewInjuryDetail',
        'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '', 
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'PreviousInjuryDetail' => array(
        'className' => 'PreviousInjuryDetail',
        'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

and Team

```
public $hasOne = array(

    'TrainingDetail' => array( 
        'className' => 'TrainingDetail',
        'foreignKey' => 'team_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Player' => array(
        'className' => 'Player',
        'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

I also copied the isOwnedBy method into every model as per the Auth tutorial. Has anyone got any advice as to how I solve this?

Comment: It seems like you should be more concerned with implementing ACL, not authentication. Also, if you're not specifying conditions, fields, etc. you do not need to put them in; removing them will make your code a bit cleaner.

Comment: Forgive me, PHP is not my core language, I'm a Java/C# guy mostly and I'm not even sure what ACL is. I dont have enough time to redesign the whole project to fit the sample in the ACL tutorial, this project needs to be finished in a few days. What would you recommend under these circumstances?

Comment: ACL is just a way of defining roles and giving users certain permissions. Theres a script that will allow you to add ACOs (your controller actions) automatically, and then unless you have a lot of roles adding code that gives certain users roles should be pretty easy.

Comment: The grim reality is that this code needs to be rewritten using aliases (instead of the weird hasOne Player relationship), and the Illness and Injury models need to be condensed (no need to have prev/contd/new). That'd make life a lot simpler but given your timeframe is probably not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I've settled on reading the user_id after the submit button is clicked. This causes duplicate entries if the back button is clicked but users are still prevented from seeing other users data. If we do ever take this to production I will certainly read up more on ACL and aliases.